# Android Studio Kotlin code coverage not showing highlight in gutter

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-testing

So I am running tests with code coverage in Android studio 3.1.4.

If I run on a Java class it shows the highlighted bars in the gutter just fine. However, if it is a Kotlin file then it only shows the colored bar next to the class name. . It also does not show the percentages in the project view.

Any solution for this ?

I am not using Jacoco just the built in intelliJ code coverage tool.

Comment: Have the same issue, changing runner to JaCoCo didn't help :-/